# Display Issue react-easy-crop with React MUI Dialog

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, next.js, material-ui

I am struggling to fix the display of MUI Dialog with react-easy-crop . I want to display the dialog perfectly with react-easy-crop. However, react-easy-crop is covering the entire dialog. I tried to use the z-index but its not working.

```
 <Dialog open={openDialog} onClose={handleDialogClose} maxWidth='lg' fullWidth={true}>
        <DialogTitle>Crop Image</DialogTitle>

        <DialogContent>
          {src && (
            <ReactEasyCrop
              image={src}
              crop={crop}
              zoom={zoom}
              aspect={1}
              onCropChange={onCropChange}
              onZoomChange={onZoomChange}
              onCropComplete={handleCropComplete}
              cropShape='round'
            />
          )}
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleSaveCroppedImage} color='primary'>
            Save
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={handleDialogClose} color='primary'>
            Cancel
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
```

[image: Dialog Output]